# Which Biography of Einstein

Tags: identification-request, biography

When I was in school, meaning early 2000's, I read a book that seemed older at the time. It was a biography of Einstein and also delved into explaining some of the science and math behind his theories at the appropriate times. I remember illustrations with stick figure based simple line drawings to accompany these segments. I cannot remember the title and looking through the biographies of Einstein is daunting to say the least, but I've tried. Note that this book may no longer be published.

Illustrations of note are a baseball being thrown on a train and frames of reference being draw as rectangles traveling through space. Again, these are simple stick figures and line drawings.

Can anyone perhaps point to some possibilities I can look into getting. I'd like to try to find another copy.

Comment: Could it be [*The Education of T. C. Mits* by Lililan Lieber](http://www.physicscentral.com/explore/writers/lieber.cfm)?

Comment: Negative, it was certainly a biography of Einstein. It spoke about his marriage. The illustrations where less fanciful than the cover art of that book. My copy had an image of Einstein on it. An example of the drawing would be a stick figure throwing a circle atop a train.

Comment: Well, it's not quite a biography, but it fits some of your aesthetic requirements: the cover photo is a sort of computerized image of Einstein, and the illustrations inside are simple, stick figure line drawings. The purpose of the book is to explain a lot of his work in a matter that people can understand. The book is called [*Understanding Einstein's Theories of Relativity: Man's New Perspective on the Cosmos* by Stan Gibilisco](https://books.google.com/books/about/Understanding_Einstein_s_theories_of_rel.html?id=fiFPAQAAIAAJ) (the link doesn't seem to show the cover properly).

Comment: Could it possibly have been [*Subtle is the Lord*](https://books.google.de/books?id=h3etQgAACAAJ) by Abraham Pais? While I've never read it myself, from what I heard about it it could fit your description. And it definitely has an image of Einstein on the cover.